# How do I add padded zeros to a loop count?

Tags: vba, vbscript

Consider a simple loop:

```
i = 0
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    MsgBox (Right("000" + i, 3))
    i = i + 1
Next
```

I was under the assumption this would return (with 200 files in the current folder):

```
001
002
...
099
...
200
```

But it does not. Any other solution I found online by Googling "adding padded zeros to loop count" (and its variations), do not work.

Can somebody show me how to do this (with as little code as possible)? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the output you get?

Comment: "But it does not." Then what **does** it do?

Comment: I'm not a VB programmer but I would've thought that would work too... It isn't getting confused with the number is it? Is it worth casting that to a string before the concatenation operation?

Comment: It just outputs 1, 2, 3 etc. So I guess it ignores the padding because it considers i an integer. But i would like not having to convert it into a string because it makes the code more messy I guess. I'm assuming there's an obscure number formatting possible that I missed?

Comment: You can also pad with; `format$(i, "000")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that the "+" operator does a mathematical + because you have a string that can be converted to a number and a real number, so "000" + 5 gives the number 5.  You need the "&" operator here, which concatenates text (in this case the result will be "0005" you expect).

Comment: if you want to have a total of three numbers, instead of just three leading zeros all the time, use the Rigth() function. 'finalString = Right(stringWithZeros,3);'

Comment: Thanks! I figured out myself that ´right(1000 + 1, 3)´ also does the job :-)

Comment: @Pr0no Just don't use mathematical operators for string operations. Even though `+` is officially allowed for string concatenations (which I consider a design flaw in the language), its "overloaded" functionality in combination with automatic type conversion is prone to creating problems like the one you encountered, which could easily be avoided by using the concatenation operator (`&`).

Answer (score 0):

The following might do:

```
MsgBox (Format(i,"000"))
```

Answer (score 0):

With your requirement, the length of zeros to be padded is known. Below is a more flexible for your purpose. Say when over thousand files is in the folder, you cannot say the 1001'st file is the first file (your code fixed it to be 3 digits).

Basically if you know the max length of the number to be padded, you can make a function out of it **PadNum()** below.

```
Dim PadLen
PadLen = Len(CStr(objFolder.Files.Count))

i = 0
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    i = i + 1
    MsgBox PadNum(i) & vbTab & objFile.Name
Next
'...
Function PadNum(x)
    PadNum = String(PadLen - Len(CStr(x)), "0") & x
End Function
```